# Laravel 5: return other route path by name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to return other route path by name (something like `/home/{page?}`), I tried `Route()`

https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_route

```
Route('home');     //return http://localhost/home
Route('home',[1]);     //return http://localhost/home/1
Route('home',[1],false);     //return /home/1
```

but I need to return the system path: `/home/{page?}`, and `home` is not current route,

thanks,

Update:

Route definition:

```
Route::GET('home/{page?}' ,array('uses'=>'News@home', 'as'=>'home'));
```

Comment: Can you show your `routes/web.php` file where you defined this route?

Comment: @Jerodev added to question

Comment: What do you mean by the other route part? What is the exact string you want to get?

Comment: I want to get this `home/{page?}`, and this is not current requested route

Comment: May I ask why you would want this? There is no simple way to do this, you will have to get this from the application router collection.

Comment: I need to fill route's parameters based on name, `route()` method fill route parameters based on order,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill in route parameters by name by using an associative array in the `route()` function.

Like so:

```
$url = route('home', ['page' => 1]);
```

This way you can put the parameters in any order in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$urldata = route('home', ['page' => 1]);
```